# Apache Flink trigger that fires when state size threshold is reached

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-batch

I would like to implement an apache flink trigger that will fire when the state accumulates 256MB.
I would like to do this because my sink is writing parquet files to hdfs and i would like to run ETL on them later, which means I don’t want too small or too large files, and my source(apache kafka topic) is changing in volume constantly.

I didn’t find a way to do it. I found some the StateObject interface that have the size() function. Didn’t find a way to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Flink FileSink with the [Parquet bulk format](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/), and have a rolling policy that constrains the file size, but rolls based on your maximum allowable latency.